# How do I create methods at run time in a pre-existing class?

Tags: c#, dynamic

I'm using the fluent pattern for helping with unit testing, and result object building.  The biggest pain point of the fluent builder pattern is having to define all these With____ methods for each and every property that I might want to set.

When it comes to an object with maybe 30 fields that I might want to set, I don't exactly want to write out 30 methods that all pretty much do the same thing. I'd rather just write out something dynamic that can handle all the similar logic for me.

For example (psuedo code)

```
for each property in this.properties 
  define method( property.name with 
    return type: this.class,
    parameter types: [property.type]){

    set property property.name, parameters[0]
    return this
  }
```

Here is what I have so far in `c#`

```
 var properties = typeof(EngineModelBuilder).GetProperties();
 foreach (var property in properties){
   // how do I create a method here with the property?
   // a property has .PropertyType and a .Name
   // and the return type is always going to be 'this'
 }
```

For reference, here is how a normal fluent builder method looks:

```
    public EngineModelBuilder WithDescription(string description)
    {
        _description = description;
        return this;
    }
```

Comment: Would it not be better to use an existing library for this such as [_AutoFixture_](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture)...? From the documentation: _"Among other features, it offers a generic implementation of the Test Data Builder pattern."_

Comment: that won't work, as we want to manually define our default values for each "complex type"...

Comment: Are you trying to modify the class at run-time? If so, you can't. If not, what _are_ you really trying to do? Can you emit code at build time, e.g. as code for a partial class that gets compiled into the class you want? Do you really want to be able to e.g. call a `WithDescription()` method, or can you call a general-purpose method that takes the name of a property? What you "have so far" really isn't much; you should try harder, to implement something that does a better job illustrating what it is exactly you want to achieve, and what specific problem you are having figuring out.

Comment: I gave psuedo of exactly what I want - which is pretty clear. I'm going to post the solution that I came up with which is not as elegant, but works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the class I came up with. It utilizes C#'s dynamic object to use the "method_missing" approach of run-time functionality.

Note that method_missing is from Ruby, and is commonly used for this kind of dynamic behavior.

[DynamicBuilder.cs](https://github.com/NullVoxPopuli/Procedural-Builder/commit/2bfecada78d3abce766faa9350130f5d7e1b4f63):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Dynamic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PGenCore
{
    /// <summary>
    /// TODO: test different field retreival techniques (using fields from T, and managing in a Dictionary)
    ///  - how would we define defaults?
    ///
    ///
    /// Usage:
    ///   dynamic objectBuilder = new ObjectBuilder();
    ///   var object = objectBuilder
    ///     .WithObjectFieldName(appropriateValue)
    ///     .WithObjectField(appropriateValue2)
    ///     .Build();
    ///
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Type to Build</typeparam>
    public class DynamicBuilder<T> : DynamicObject
    {
        #region List of FieldInformation
        protected FieldInfo[] FieldInfos;
        public FieldInfo[] FieldInformation
        {
            get
            {
                // don't GetFields all the time
                if (FieldInfos != null) return FieldInfos;

                FieldInfos = this.GetType().GetFields(
                    BindingFlags.Public |
                    BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                    BindingFlags.Instance);

                return FieldInfos;
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Utility

        /// <summary>
        /// converts FieldName to _fieldName
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="publicName"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static string PublicNameToPrivate(string publicName)
        {
            var propertyLowerFirstLetterName = char.ToLower(
                publicName[0]) + publicName.Substring(1);

            var privateName = "_" + propertyLowerFirstLetterName;

            return privateName;
        }
        #endregion

        #region Method is Missing? Check for With{FieldName} Pattern

        /// <summary>
        /// Inherited form DynamicObject.
        /// Ran before each method call.
        ///
        ///
        /// Note: Currently only works for setting one value
        ///  at a time.
        ///   e.g.: instance.Object = value
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="binder"></param>
        /// <param name="args"></param>
        /// <param name="result"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public override bool TryInvokeMember(
             InvokeMemberBinder binder,
             object[] args,
             out object result)
        {

            var firstArgument = args[0];
            var methodName = binder.Name;
            var propertyRootName = methodName;

            // following the builder pattern,
            // methods that participate in building T,
            // return this so we can chain building methods.
            result = this;

            // for booleans, since the field / property should be named as
            // a question, using "With" doesn't make sense.
            // so, this logic is only needed when we are not setting a
            // boolean field.
            if (!(firstArgument is bool))
            {
                // if we are not setting a bool, and we aren't starting
                // with "With", this method is not part of the
                // fluent builder pattern.
                if (!methodName.Contains("With")) return false;
                propertyRootName = methodName.Replace("With", "");
            }

            // convert to _privateFieldName
            // TODO: think about dynamicly having fields in a Dictionary,
            //  rather than having to specify them
            var builderFieldName = PublicNameToPrivate(propertyRootName);

            // find matching field name, given the method name
            var fieldInfo = FieldInformation
                .FirstOrDefault(
                    field => field.Name == builderFieldName
                 );

            // if the field was not found, abort
            if (fieldInfo == null) return false;

            // set the field to the value in args
            fieldInfo.SetValue(this, firstArgument);
            return true;
        }

        #endregion

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns the built object
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public virtual T Build()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// for any complex associations
        /// - building lists of items
        /// - building anything else that isn't just an easy vavlue.
        /// </summary>
        public virtual void SetRelationshipDefaults()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Tests of usage can be seen here: https://github.com/NullVoxPopuli/Procedural-Builder/blob/master/ProceduralBuilder.Test/DynamicBuilderTest.cs